# Create Temporary Index for bulk operation and Delete after its completed

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-server-2012, bulk

I am moving bulk data to archive tables. Some times query returns up to 4500 k records, which takes about 2:15 minutes for a table of 40 columns.

I want too increase the performance for the selection by **using a temporary non clustered index and drop that index after select operation**.

I am also setting data base logging to bulk logging while performing the bulk operation.

Will that really help, or it is even possible o not.

Any other suggestions are also welcome.